# Excel VBA - After Row Delete Workheet Sorts Outside of Filter

Tags: excel, filter, vba

In the worksheet I'm currently working on I set up a filter to include all rows excluding the total row (I've red-boxed the blue numbers on the left that seem to identify the rows that are included in the filter range):

[image]

Then after deleting the row between the total and the end of the worksheet (row 20) with:

```
Rows(iLastWizardRow - 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

the row deletes and it still appears to not be included in the filter:

[image]

However when I then sort the worksheet it includes row "21", which isn't even blue and appears not to be included in the filter:

[image]

How do I exclude the total row from being sorted with the rest of the rows?  It looks like the filter already stops at row 20 so I don't know how to proceed.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Yo should use a Table, with all your data, and then add a totals row (an option the Table Design Ribbon). That Totals Row will be always down.

Comment: Nope, I'm not redesigning the whole thing into a table for your "should".  The question is: 1) how can I exclude that row from sorting as it is and 2) Why is it including it in the sort in the first place?

Comment: I don't know how you are sorting, but when you delete the row your Total row is added to the data so when you sort it includes the Total row. If you just hide the row it will sort without the Total row.  Or you can set the specific range to sort.

Comment: Thanks GMalc59 - that's precisely what I ended up doing, hiding the row.  If you add this as an answer to my question I will accept it as the solution.